# windows 10 restore from backup on a different drive

Tags: windows-10, restore, windows-7-backup

**Scenario**

During or shortly after the standard windows user log on my computer would immediately power off. I tried reverting software back as best I could with no luck. I've since reinstalled a new copy of windows and all my backups are on a second drive in the computer (drive D:)

**Question**

`System and Security > Backup and Restore (Windows 7) > Restore` has a button for "select another backup to restore files from" yet I cannot see my D drive backups.

How can I restore to a backup from drive D using "Backup and Restore (Windows 7)" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swapped out the graphics card to see if that was the issue, **no success**

I installed linux to see if the OS was the issue, **no success**

I swapped out the PSU to see if that was the issue, **success**

To use your existing backup:

1. boot into windows safe mode (either do a manual power off twice in a row or use a usb windows recovery device to enter safemode)
2. go to "advanced options"
3. choose to restart windows from a backup